# PHP Delete User Data From Table On Button Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a code that works fine except one thing. When you click onto the `Delete` button, a modal box appers and it shows 2 buttons. When you click onto the `OK` button it should delete that user's data which you clicked. But this is deletes the user who has the lowest `ID`. But if I removes the modal box opening function and simpy just put a `href='delete.php?id=".$roww['id']."'` it works fine. Any idea how to solve this?

Code from the index.php:

```
include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here
$records = mysqli_query($db,"select * from accounts"); // fetch data from database
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {}

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phplogin");
if ($conn-> connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
}
$ssql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$result =  $conn-> query($ssql);
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
   while ($roww = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
       $id = $roww['id'];
       echo "
           <span>".$roww['username']."</span>
           <span>".$roww['email']."</span>
           <a onclick='pop()'>Delete</a>

           // Delete modal
           <div id='box'>
                <img src='/assets/images/svg/rf-alert.svg' width='64px'>
                <h1>Attention!</h1>
                <p>You are going to delete this user permanently.</p>
                <a class='close' href='delete.php?id=".$roww['id']."' title='".$roww['id']."'>Delete</a> // This button should delete the data from the MySQL table
                <a class='close' onclick='pop()'>Cancel</a>
           </div>
       ";
} else { echo "0 result";}
}
$conn-> close();
```

Comment: Think about your logic here.... if you have 3 accounts in the list, then `<div id='box'>` will be created 3 times. How did you imagine the Javascript was going to know which one was which, in order to open the correct one? An ID is pointless if it doesn't actually uniquely identify the item in question.

Comment: Why are you executing your select query twice and connecting to the database twice. If you are going to use copy/paste to mashup some code, you also have to look at it to make sure it then makes sense when you put the bits together

Comment: And the `} else { echo "0 result";}` is in the wrong place. Does that code actually run, I doubt it

Comment: Yes, the code runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id='box'>
```

All modals will have the same ID, may it be related to opening the first modal always? Try with something like:

```
<div id='box".$roww['id']."'>
```

Also you'll have to edit the pop() function to something like pop(id);

A better option would be create the modal dinamically.

Comment: One question. How do you mean to use `pop(id)` ? Where should I put is or what?

Comment: You're launching the PopUp with this code:
`<a onclick='pop()'>Delete</a>`

The pop() function probably opens the **first div with "box" id**. You may have to edit it to accept a parameter indicating what pop-up you want to show.


A better option might be creating a custom function like _mypop(value)_ that edits the link href inside the box div to `'delete.php?id=' + value`, and calls the pop() function. 

You also would need to change the delete link to: `<a onclick='mypop(".$roww['id'].")'>Delete</a>`